# OpenCV for Android - OpenCL support

Tags: android, opencv

I've been trying to figure out if OpenCL should be supported on OpenCV 3.0 on Android, but could not find a clear answer. At my end, I get a negative answer from "haveOpenCL" for several devices. Can someone tell me if it is supported by default, and if not - is there a way to enable it?

Thanks,
yakobom

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use OpenCL through OpenCV on android devices.

You need to enable the option to use OpenCL functions. When you build opencv, if you're using cmake, type in the terminal

```
cmake ..
```

wherever your CMakeLists.txt file is and check to see whether it says "OpenCL ON" in the stuff it spits out.

If it's OFF, then you need to add the flag

```
WITH_OPENCL=ON
```

when you're building. If you've got a file like build_opencv.sh or something, it will have the cmake command in it, next to which you'll need to add something like

```
 -DWITH_OPENCL=ON
```

You can do the same thing if you're running cmake from the terminal directly. Just add the flag when you run cmake.

Check to see if your build output now says OpenCL YES.

Another thing you probably need to remember is to call

```
setUseOpenCL(true)
```

in your code. I didn't do that and I still got haveOpenCL() as true, but you never know.

Comment: Hi Neamah, thanks for your answer. I have found this flag in my searches, but since I was using the formal release and not building on my own, I first wanted to make sure it is supported on Android, since the documentation for OpenCV in general suggests this should be on by default... I will probably try it out, but do you have any evidance that this works on Android?